# Extract numpy array columns into dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm creating manually a dictionary of features and numpy array.

```
columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
features = {'a': df_train.values[:, 0],
            'b': df_train.values[:, 1],
            'c': df_train.values[:, 2],
            'd': df_train.values[:, 3]}
```

`df_train` is a Pandas dataframe originated from `pandas.read_csv()`

I'm using this code to simplify it:

```
features = {c: df_train.values[:, i] for i, c in enumerate(columns)}
```

Is there a more Pythonic way? (dict with zip for example?)

Comment: Why can't you just rename the columns using your list and then call `to_dict()`? Besides that,  I don't see any issue with your current approach.

Comment: You got it in a single line. That's as Pythonic as it gets I am afraid. You can probably use different methods as you suggest, but the outcome will be the same. Are you implying a more computationally efficient way?

Comment: My number of columns is quite small, not sure if computationally efficiency is a concern, just wondering if there would be a better option for readability/existing library. Thanks

Comment: No, I don't think there's a more pythonic way. Following up on the comment by @b-fg you don't _necessarily_ get "pythonic" from having a 1-liner but, in this case, it's perfectly readable and efficient.

Comment: @roganjosh You are right to be fair. But normally writing in fewer lines makes it more [pythonic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119913/how-can-i-learn-to-effectively-write-pythonic-code) since you are using the language more naturally. In terms of readability, maybe there are better ways, but that reads very well in my opinion anyways.

Comment: @b-fg spend a bit more time on SO and you'll see some catastrophic 1-liners :P. The dict comprehension here is fine, but there's also a broader misunderstanding with some people that cramming everything into one line with horrible time complexity wins.

Comment: @roganjosh, Yes understand where you come from hehe. And we are on the same page ;)

Comment: _"dict with zip"_? Yes, there is: `dict(zip(columns, df_train.values.T))`

Comment: Hi @PaulPanzer can you promote this to answer? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the transpose:

```
dict(zip(columns, df_train.values.T))
```

or

```
{k: v for k, v in zip(columns, df_train.values.T)}
```